# WooCommerce how to select the correct item data from wp_woocommerce tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce, the item data is saved in wp_woocommerce_items and wp_woocommerce_itemmeta tables, and I am trying to print a specific user's order data (aka All the products and their cost) on a page. However I am not sure how print only the data that belongs to the specific user.

I have tried creating a relation to the two tables to link the order_item_ids, but I had no success. My current error and code below:

"WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id LIKE '109'' at line 4]"

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items, wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
WHERE wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id = itemmeta_items.wp_woocoommerce_items_order_item_id
AND wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id LIKE '109";
```

The database looks like the following:
From wp_woocommerce_itemmeta:
[image: From wp_woocommerce_itemmeta]
 and from wp_woocommerce_items:
[image: From wp_woocommerce_items]

For clarification: I want to print out the product name and it's cost from the order 109, but I am not sure how to get the right values from the itemmeta table. this should also work if the customer has ordered multiple items.

Any help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: "I have tried creating a relation" > you  mean a 3rd table? Have you tried JOINs?

Comment: @Michael Oh yeah, as I said on the post, I tried creating a relation between the two tables by creating a new table that linked the wp_woocommerce_itemmeta and wp_woocommerce_items together. Even without this "wp_woocommerce_itemmeta.item_order_id = wp_woocommerce_items.order_item_id" wouldn't work.

Comment: The way to join data from two tables is - [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).